# How to get the hex function read from right to left

Tags: php, mysql, hex, endianness

I'm currently having a problem reading the HEX string. I have a DEC values written to the database with a value of 5000 in HEX is 1388, but when the data is written to the database in HEX format, it is reversed into 8813.

This is how It got into database :

> **8813**00000000000

Now I want to query the HEX data to convert to DEC and display it on my web page, how do I get the HEX value from right to left, which means I have to get the HEX value 13 first, and then will get to the value 88 so that when displayed on the web, the number will be 5000. If anyone has a way to help me, please comment to let me know. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @brombeer So what is that for due?

Comment: Sounds like "big endian" vs "little endian".  What _hardware_ are you using.  What code did you use to get the bytes before converting to hex?  Perhaps use `REVERSE()`?

Comment: @RickJames I see what you're talking about. So for that, I think It get into database with Little Endian. So Do we have any way to convert It in to DEC?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(5000);
+-----------+
| HEX(5000) |
+-----------+
| 1388      |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Apparently you PHP code is more complex than that; please show it to us so we can help you fix it.

That `SELECT` should result in the same output *regardless* of the endinaness of the underlying hardware.  (MySQL hides such differences.)